# Как отследить изменение значения input до потери фокуса?

Tags: jquery, input

Пытаюсь сделать аналог вот такого блока ([Прямые рейсы авиакомпании](http://www.aviasales.ru/airlines/adria-airways)). Пишу логику фильтра у поля "поиск":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На каждое изменение значения в поле прохожу по списку маршрутов и скрываю те из них, в названии которых нет подстроки введённой в поле "поиск".

Подвесил обработчик на событие `jquery change` - всё работает но `change` наступает **при потере полем фокуса**, а мне нужно, чтобы обработчик запускался и тогда, когда **фокус ещё на поле** поиска.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода в вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input').on('input keyup', function(e) {
    //детаем дело
});
```

Comment: Работает, но не отслеживает backspace =(

Comment: Работать должно. У вас какой браузер?

Comment: @maler1988 в обоих ответах используются события `input` и `keyup`, которые вместе покрывают все адекватные способы ввода и изменения данных у `<input>` пользователем. Причем тот же _backspace_ должен работать благодаря `keyup` даже в старых IE.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. У меня Firefox + Chrome

Answer (score 5):

Абстрактный пример для демонстрации работы обработчика событий `keyup` и `input` (пригодится как минимум для ситуации, когда текст в `<input>` вставлен через контекстное меню, вызываемое при клике правой клавишей мыши по `<input>`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $elements = $('#list .element');
    $('#select').on('keyup input', function() {
        var value = this.value;
        $elements.hide();
        $elements.filter(':contains("' + value + '")').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="select" />
<ul id="list">
    <li class="element">Париж</li>
    <li class="element">Лондон</li>
    <li class="element">Москва</li>
    <li class="element">Мадрид</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не хватает события "input" для отслеживания, в том числе и копипаста.

Comment: @Deonis разве что для вставки с помощью мыши. Для `Ctrl + V` или `Shift + Insert` `keyup` вполне достаточно. Добавил в ответ событие `input`.

Comment: Дык, именно про мышь и идет речь. )) А изменение значений с помощью "shortcuts" - это те же клавиатурные события.

Answer (score 1):

Одного `input` достаточно. При использовании дополнительно метода `keyup` и при нажатии на кнопку клавиатуры возникают два события. Соответственно, если идёт запрос на сервер, то либо туда пойдут два запроса, либо нужно будет изгаляться и отсекать лишние. Так что, если вам неинтересны браузеры ниже Internet Explorer 10, то это лишняя заморочка.

```js
$('elem').on('input', function(e) {
    //делаем дело
});
```